# Suggest C regex scanner (stream reader)

Tags: c++, c, regex, parsing

I am looking for a regular expressions library in C/C++ which does not provide the common API regex(string, pattern) but rather allows to construct a finite state machine (based on the pattern(s)) and I would just call

```
fsm = create_fsm();
add_pattern(fsm, "foo", hookFoo);
add_pattern(fsm, "bar", hookBar);
compile_fsm(fsm);
while ((c = fgetc(file) != EOF) {
   next_char(fsm, c);
}
```

And if the pattern would be matched, hookFoo(match start, match end) would be called?
Or something similar to that, this is just the concept. I'd like to search for multiple regexps in long, long lines. Ideally if it could be filled also in reverse direction for backwards search.
As the expressions are known only during runtime, Flex (or similar parser generator) is not an option.

**EDIT:**
Although I have marked lexertl as the right answer, it appears that it is not what I was looking for. It needs to go back the stream; I don't want to use memory for remembering the past (other than constant-sized such as rememebering the last character). Imagine it as when I call ++iterator all other iterators should be invalidated.

Comment: out of curiosity, you are asking for one in C/C++. Do you know of one for another language?

Comment: https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NPEG  has an iterator you can extend and implements PEG - use the language workbench to export your parse tree.

Comment: AK4749: No, I have just specified this as I want to use it in C++ application. But if you know about any such library in different language, feel free to comment. Java Scanner could be of use (as it accepts streams) although not as powerful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [lexertl](http://www.benhanson.net/lexertl.html) comes a long way towards your requirements. It supports both adding regular expressions at run-time and a 'restartable' lexer. It will give you a token for each recognized 'rule'.

[boost::spirit::lex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex.html) uses lexertl as a default implementation and it adds semantic actions.

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a good fit as it can take just the iterator, not the whole string. I just hope it's fast enough with all the infernal OOP ;-) Thanks! I'll look at it and check your answer.

Comment: Sorry for unchecking the answer, but see my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

There is hyperscan library from Intel. It provides api to search for multiple regular expressions in a data stream. See http://intel.github.io/hyperscan/dev-reference/runtime.html#streaming-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own functions using functions offered by `#include<regex.h>` like `regcomp`, and `regexec`

example

```
int  match_patterns(char *pch,char *pattern)
{
    regex_t             *regex;
    regmatch_t          *result;
    int                 err_no = 0;
    int                 start = 0;

    regex = (regex_t *) calloc(1,sizeof(regex_t));
    if((err_no = regcomp(regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED)) != 0)
    {
        size_t          length;
        char            *buffer;
        length = regerror (err_no, regex, NULL, 0);
        buffer = malloc(length);
        regerror (err_no, regex, buffer, length);
        free(buffer);
        regfree(regex);
        return -1; //error
    }
    result = (regmatch_t *) calloc(1,sizeof(regmatch_t));
    if(result == NULL)
    {
        return -1; //error
    }
    while(regexec(regex, pch+start, 1, result, 0) == 0)
    {
        start +=result->rm_eo;
    }
    regfree(regex);
    free(regex);
    if((result->rm_so == 0)&&(result->rm_eo == strlen(pch)))
    {
        return 0; //OK
    }
    return -1; //error
}
```

This function will return 0 if the `pch` string match with regexp pattern `pattern` and return -1 otherwise.

example

```
int main()
{
    if (match_patterns("1234.abc", "[0-9]+.[a-d]+")==0)
        printf("OK!\n");
    else
        printf("NOK!\n");

}
```

The `match_patterns()` in this case will return 0

If you use this function do not forget to add the following iclude:

```
#include<regex.h>
#include<string.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for a long response, but you've probably missed two important qualities I am seeking for:
1) I can't have whole string (the one pointed to by pch in your code) in memory at once, and I can hardly find the "borders" where the string could be splitted.
2) I wan't to match multiple regular expressions at once, not to look for them one after another.

Comment: my answer is just an example of how to use functions offered by the <regex.h> and now it's up to you to start developing functions reltaed to your need and then back again if you are blocked some where in your function

Comment: And my question was for (cite) 'regular expressions library which does not provide the common API' where <regex.h> can be considered the common stuff with regex(string, pattern).

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling around, I have found the RE2 library http://code.google.com/p/re2/ - this states to be a fast one implementation (with speed comparable to grep or awk) with the right theory in background and can offer memory limits.
RE2::FindAndConsume seems to be the right API.

**EDIT:** Nope (again). FindAndConsume only finds incrementaly matches in one string but does not allow to pass multiple chunks of the data stream :( And by the way when the match is found the machine travels back to see where the match actually started (although this is not such a big problem as it shouldn't do that during forward search, as e.g. **lexertl** does.